# What does this phrase from shapelys nearest_points() documentation mean?

Tags: shapely

In [the shapely user manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for `nearest_points()` there is the following remark

> Note that the nearest points may not be existing vertices in the
> geometries.

What is existing vertices in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: the resulting shortest-distance points might not lie on the exact vertices of your input geometries.

Look at the following example:

```py
import shapely

line  = shapely.geometry.LineString([(-1,0),(1,0)])
poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0,0.5),(1,1.5),(-1,1.5)])

near_line, near_poly = shapely.ops.nearest_points(line, poly)

print(near_line.wkt)
# 'POINT (0 0)'

print(near_poly.wkt)
# 'POINT (0 0.5)'
```

Notice how the `near_line` object is a point at `(0,0)`, which is not a vertex in the original `line` object. While the point `(0,0)` is **contained** in the original `line` object, it was *NOT* an actual vertex.

That is what the documentation is referring to.

Comment: Ha, I wouldn't expect it to work in any other way, so I was just confused by this note. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No worries! Glad the example helped =)